# XCode Jigsaw Puzzle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create a jigsaw puzzle app for iOS. From my searches through the internet, there really aren't any tutorials on the subject. Does anyone know of any links to good tutorials or tutorials on games that anyone knows of? Thanks. By the way, iOS4 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cocos2D: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Relevant for jigsaw pieces: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6363

Comment: @andrew... Can you update your answer as the link of jigsaw pieces you have shared is no longer valid.

Comment: @andrew... as Usamaman Said link is not valid, pelase update your answer

Answer (score 1):

I am also thinking that divided original image with masking but it might be bad idea for us and also complicated to manage it. So For user who is beginner for **jigsaw puzzle** then [This is the best question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810798/cropping-image-with-transparency-in-iphone) 
and you will also find [source code from git.](https://github.com/GuntisTreulands/JigsawDemo.)

Please hats off this man who solve your problem. I know this should be not an answer but should be comment but If I will put it as comment then may be use who have problem with **jigsaw puzzle** he/she can not find it easily so. I am putting it as answer.